# Colocar form de pesquisa na direita da navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3

Estou usando Bootstrap e coloquei um form de pesquisa dentro de uma navbar simples.

O problema é que eu não consigo tirar o form de perto do titulo, gostaria que ele ficasse alinhado para direita da navbar.

Esse é o HTML:

```html
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

              <div class="navbar-brand"> TITULO </div>




            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                
               
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
                    <form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" id="search-form" name="search-form">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Find in title or description" id="query" name="query" value="">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Coloquei no Bootply para facilitar:

http://www.bootply.com/8LqYRTJOyq

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pra isso utilize a classe `navbar-right`:

`<div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 navbar-right">`

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!